# Magento customer entity table remove UNIQUE KEY in table properties

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I need to change default customer_entity table description in magento with my plugin's setup script, is it possible to make it remove the `UNIQUE KEY` field ?

The magento `customer_entity` table structure described as:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type Id',
  `attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set Id',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  ...
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`),
  ...
```

So what I need is to make it remove this one with installation script

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`)
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? Can't you just remove that line from the script?

Comment: according to magento reference it is should be done with install script not with the sql, the code i provided above is just a dump that describes a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could run sql queries in an update/install script:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql= 'ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` DROP INDEX `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID`'
$installer->run($sql);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Or you could do it in the "magento way" like this (untested code!)

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->getConnection()->dropKey('customer_entity', 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID')
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2):

did it that way:

```
    <?php

    $installer = $this;
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $table = $installer->getTable('customer/entity');
    $connection->dropIndex($table, 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID');
    $installer->endSetup();
```